# How to find a basis for $R^3$ which contains a basis of im(C)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Find a basis for $R^3$ which contains a basis of $im(C)$ (image of C), where

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3&4\\\ 2 & -4 & 6& -2\\ -1 & 2 & -3 &1   \end{pmatrix}$$

I managed to row-reduce the matrix to

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3&4\\\ 0 & 8 & 0& 6\\ 0 & 0 & 0 &4   \end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, a basis of $im(C)$ is given by the leading columns:

$$Basis = {\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\-1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2\\-4\\2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}4\\-2\\1 \end{pmatrix}}$$

However, what does the question mean by "Find a basis for $R^3$ which contains a basis of im(C)?According to the answers, one possible answer is:

{$\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\-1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2\\-4\\2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a calculation error, as the rank of your matrix is actually two, not three. If the rank of $C$ was three, you could have chosen any basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (not necessarily even consisting of some of the columns of $C$). But in your case, we have

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 6 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix} = 3 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}, \\
\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{3}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} + \frac{5}{4} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

so the last two columns depend linearly on the first two columns. To find a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ which contains a basis of $\operatorname{im}(C)$, choose any two linearly independent columns of $C$ such as the first two and add to them any third vector which is linearly independent of the chosen columns of $C$.

Comment: Hey levap. I found my row-reduction mistake. After performing it once again, I found that the basis for im(C) is the first two columns of C, i.e. <1,2,-1> and <2,-4,2>. I'm still a bit confused on how to find the last vector to get the basis for $R^3$, still a bit confused what we're trying to do. Thanks

Comment: @Programmer: You need to find a third vector which is not a linear combination of the first two vectors. You can do it in many ways - find a vector such that the determinant of the $3 \times 3$ matrix formed by the three vectors is non-zero, find a vector which is orthogonal to both vectors. It is easier to start playing with the "trivial" vectors $e_i$ (standard basis vectors) and see if they are enough and if not, modify them accordingly.